# InputTextArray[inputLength - 1]

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function handleInput() {
    inputLength = inp.value.length
    inputTextArray = inp.value.split(' ')
    console.log(inputTextArray) // Prints the actual arry after splitting.
    console.log(inputTextArray[0]) // Prints The 1st character as I type but further typing it prints the 'undefined'
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" onKeyUp='handleInput()'>
```

Comment: I made an edit so it's a working example. However the behaviour you describe does not happen.

Comment: colud you explain what is the problem? an what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not activ.
handleInput();

Comment: It's not my whole code. It's only a part of that. It's genuine; if I ama getting something in my console, then it's obvious I would have called the function on Input.

Comment: Ok, I don't see what you want to get. can you write again?